# How to maintain session on a phonegap android app

Tags: android, session, cordova

I am new to phonegap development and currently developing an app that will run on android, i-phone and on windows phone. But getting problem in handling session from phonegap app - I got few post here on stack overflow but that was only for iphone using appDelegate.m defining cookie storage and also I got few post for only android storing session in HttpClient object coded in java - but is there anything on phonegap side to handle session - because then we can use the same code for all 3 devices ( iphone, android, windows ).

Probably I may sounds some sort of odd but I am really undecided as can't find any clue how to maintain the session and how to use the same session on consecutive calls to serverside script for gettinf different session specific information.

Is there any common way to achieve this that I may missed. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

With Regards,

Supriyo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless I misunderstood you, HTML5's localStorage is the way to go.

It is implemented in Phonegap, as described here: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#localStorage

Comment: yes, actually I am also now using the localStorage - nice things - anyways thanks for the reply mate

Comment: Can anyone link to an example of using localStorage to securely maintain a session with Phonegap?

Answer (score -4):

This one works for me.

```
var CheckboxValue=$("#rememberme").is("checked");
if (CheckboxValue== true)
{
    var username = $("#user").val();
    var password = $("#pass").val();
    window.localStorage.setItem("username", username);
    window.localStorage.setItem("password", password);
}
```